# Titanium flip transition flips view from top in landscape mode

Tags: ios, titanium, transition, flip

I'm doing a titanium application for IOS. I want to flip left - right between two windows.

For this, I put:

```
var helpWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.FILL,
    fullscreen : false,
    navBarHidden : true,
    backgroundColor : "#393a3a",
    orientationModes : [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT]
});
helpWindow.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT];
helpWindow.add(helpView);

var openHelpWindow = function(){
    helpWindow.open({
        transition : Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT
    });
    helpView.updateTitle();
};
var closeHelpWindow = function(){
    helpWindow.close({
        transition : Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_RIGHT
    });
};
```

This works ok in Portrait, but in Landscape, the animation flips from top to bottom or vice versa.

How can I do that the transition flips from left - right in portrait and in landscape?

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried using different animation when you are in landscape mode?

Comment: Yes, but I want to show the same animation in protrait and in landscape. Is it possible with flip animation?